# Getting rid of an unwanted pushed commit from git log

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I've read all the answers for this specific question and i know it might look as duplicate, but i don't think it is, i think that i'm asked to do something deferent and maybe i don't understand the answers and i'm not that strong in git. (using mostly source tree)

The problem is:

1. I have a project that i got while it was developed and it didn't go anywhere do i got a task to  fix it. now that it fixed and i've pushed like 30 times over the old commits of the previous developers my boss want me to remove a specific commit from the log (history) that he doesn't want to client to see (fully remove the commit form the log.
2. The issue is that my code was based on the code on the old commits, i didn't have time to start the project form scratch so i fixed the old code and went form there and i'm afraid that i dod a rebase i will delete something.
3. To be clear (i can't post the git history, sorry, but hope that someone could help). I have old pushed commits that i need to keep in the history, then in the middle I have two **pushed commits that i need to remove fully from the log and history but keep the code that was pushed in them** and then i have more pushed commits that i need to keep in the history.

Thanks for the help and sorry i didn't have any example to put here.

Comment: The main problem in practice is whether your commit history is linear, and if not, whether you need to keep it non-linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your history from the old to the current commits is linear, a simple interactive rebase and then force push would be possible. In the interactive rebase, you can squash the "bad" commits into the commits before or after, so the changes will still be there, but look like they were part of other commits.

Note you can "backup" the current state under some branch name, and after rebasing you can compare, and if you do not like the result, you can always reset hard to your backup commit.

Comment: 10x but what about if someone already pulled the master after all the pushed, what will happen when they will have a pull request again? I'me reading about interactive rebase and from what i've read and i seems like there is no way around it that if the client already pulled the pushed commits they will have to fix it on their side also? Am I wrong? I'm trying to think that i might be worth leaving it like that.. He is trying to hide what can't be hidden i think...

Comment: If anyone has received the commits already, there is nothing you can do to make them "lose" the commits. They would see both the old and the new history, and wonder why somebody did this.

Comment: That is what i was thinking... 10x.   Another thing if you don't mind, from what i've read about interactive rebase, just like rebase, if i delete a commit it will delete the code that was in that commit, no? maybe i didn't understand it but in every post i read it seems that the code behind the commit is being deleted also, so it is not just deleting the log history, it is actually deleting code, and there are warnings in every post to be sure you know what you are doing, but i'm not sure LOL

Comment: As I said in my response (feel free to upvote it), you would have to squash the commits. If you do not squash the commits, but remove them, then their changes would also be gone, yes. So I recommend you keep a backup branch and compare, making sure your code looks the same before and after your rebase.